# Error assigning with brace-enclosed initializer for character string

Tags: c++, c-strings, assignment-operator, initializer

```
struct A{
    char s[10];

};
int main()
{
    A a1;
    a1 = {"abc"};
    return 0;
}
```

It gives the following error in GCC:

```
 In function 'int main()':
8:8: error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'A' and '<brace-enclosed initializer list>')
8:8: note: candidates are:
1:8: note: A& A::operator=(const A&)
1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'const A&'
1:8: note: A& A::operator=(A&&)
1:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'A&&'
```

But works fine in Visual Studio (even no warning). So just wondering is it compiler specific? Does C++ standard say anything about this? For me GCC's behavior looks correct. But could someone please explain the fundamental behind this?

NOTE: if I initialize as `A a1={"abc"}` then it works fine in GCC. So why assignment operation doesn't work?

EDIT: what's the difference between a1 = {'a','b','c'} vs a1 = {"abc"}. The former works in GCC.

Comment: `a1 = {"abc"};` is not an initialization. It is an assignment. `A a1 = {"abc"};` is an initialization.

Comment: why a1 = {'a','b','c'} works?

Answer (score 1):

This statement:

```
a = {"abc"};  // error
```

is ill-formed, and the error message says why quite clearly. The statement is trying to do an *assignment*, but the left hand side of the assignment is an `A`, and the right hand side is a brace-init list. There is no `A::operator=` that takes a brace-init list, and so the assignment doesn't work.

---

On the other hand, this statement:

```
A a = {"abc"};  // ok
```

is *constructing* an object of type `A`, which considers all the constructors of `A`. Since `A` is an aggregate type, there is a constructor that can accept a single argument that can be used to initialize `s`.

---

This means that if you want to assign to an existing object, you can create an `A` object, and *then* assign it:

```
a = A{"abc"}; // ok
```

Comment: Thanks @cigien. No idea why VS allows this.

Comment: @BlueBird Sorry, I've no idea. I don't often compile with msvc anyway.